# Turn off ViewState validation only on one page

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 site using the DotNetNuke with many pages and custom built modules.  One of those pages (custom built module) randomly throws the following exception:

```
The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.
```

I have `validateRequest="false"` in web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" enableViewStateMac="true" enableEventValidation="true" viewStateEncryptionMode="Always">
```

The page has many controls on it and is very dynamic.  What should I do to debug such issue? Is there a way to turn off ViewState validation on that page only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following post, may help http://www.ifinity.com.au/Products/Support_Forums/forumid/8/threadid/1341/scope/posts/threadpage/2

Summary of fix:

> The viewstate is clearly being processed incorrectly and the last change was the url rewriter, so making a guess I've moved the httpmodule entry for the viewstate module in the web.config file above the urlrewriter entry in the vague hope that it would execute first. It does and everything is now working OK. There's a strong possibility I have broken something else (you know how it is) so I'm not jumping for joy yet, but it looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on my DNN 6.2.9 site with various pages that work fine under normal circumstances. However, when I do see this error in the log it always has an unusual UserAgent, for example "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Synapse)". See this thread "[What is Apache Synapse](https://superuser.com/questions/146133/what-is-apache-synapse)?" on superuser.com for some more info on this particular one. If it is malicious traffic POSTing arbitrary content it would generate this error.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  It is not the case for me since the site is not yet public.  It is still under testing, and my testers are seeing the errors on their screens.